# Create Lazy cached value for dependency resolver in C#?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm using .Net core web app.
In my app I'm using `Lazy` in order to cache a heavy time-consuming operation into the Lazy value :

```
interface IFoo
{
     Lazy<Task<int>> MyLazy { get;   set; }

}

class Foo : IFoo
{
    public Lazy<Task<int>> MyLazy { get;    set; }

    public Foo()
    {
        MyLazy = new Lazy<Task<int>>(() => /*heavy operation*/ Task.FromResult(3));
    }

}
```

Sure, I don't want to run the heavy operation in the constructor, but only when it's needed, and then cache the value. Lazy property is fine IMHO.
Worth to mention: I do plan to use `.AdddSingleton<Ifoo,Foo>`.

So now I can inject `IFoo` and get `MyLazy` property.

But I don't want the `set` to be public. I've tried to change it to `protected set` but get an error :

[image]

**Question:**

I think I'm going the wrong path here.

How can I create DI-Interface-Class which will expose a cached property of a heavy-duty operation? ( *without allowing to change it, outside `Foo`*)

*The full closure:  we need to load from our DB some rows to be used throughout the app, and don't want to load them every time.*

Comment: Do you really need explicit interface implementation or is that just part of your effort to resolve this?

Comment: @KirkLarkin part of effort.  I can't set it to private set beacuse c# won't allow. So I've tried protected. And then go this ^.  I think it's smelly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare *just* the getter in `IFoo`, like this:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    Lazy<Task<int>> MyLazy { get; } 
}
```

Then, as of C# 6, you can implement a [read-only auto-property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#read-only-auto-properties) that will both implement the interface member and provide a setter that you can use in the constructor:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public Lazy<Task<int>> MyLazy { get; }

    public Foo()
    {
        MyLazy = new Lazy<Task<int>>(() => Task.FromResult(3)); 
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can change `Foo.MyLazy` to `private set`, if you want to set it elsewhere in the class:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public Lazy<Task<int>> MyLazy { get; private set; }

    // ...
}
```